# How many ways to count permutations of "MISSISSIPPI" with the sequence "MIS" in the permutation?

Tags: combinatorics

I assumed that this problem would require counting "MIS" as one letter (x), giving us a multiset:
{x,S,I,S,S,I,P,P,I}
And we do 9! divided by the repeated letters. However, the letter "s" is in x and outside of "s". Same with "I".

So, would the answer be 9!/(4!4!2!) (including the fourth "s" and fourth "i" which is actually in x),
Or 9!/(3!3!2!)? (excluding the "s" and "i" in x)

Comment: The latter. You are permitting the multiset which includes “x”  then replacing $x$ by “MIS.”

Comment: [The direct computation](https://tio.run/##RcoxCsMwDADA3a8wXiJRyJKlX/AQCHgsGTq4RMGRhKwOfb075ubTnx/Cy1NtDLpUzCN5NRdpPagRO7TK0KtDmKb5FGIgjB@xSJH4zrNWu77@dhLu8EprLml/NOoOqeRS8rblhBgQcYw/) agrees with the latter, $5040$ is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace S,S,S,S by $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$, solve the problem with $MI_1S_1$ instead of $MIS$, and divide by $4! 4!2!$ at the end.